# Tkinter: Set variable to string input

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been working with python and Tkinter for a little while now, and have decided to make text based game. I know how to do the functions in just python, but I want to have an actual window, not just the console. I've figured out how to make a window and display a string of text... but I want to be able to type and show that text.

```
from Tkinter import *

w=Tk()

textvar="Welcome, to the PIT OF INSANLEY INTENSE THINGS... AND STUFF!!!"

def key(event):
    print event.char

t=Text(w)
t.insert(INSERT,textvar)
t.configure(state=DISABLED)
t.bind("<Key>",key)
t.pack()

w.mainloop()
```

This code makes a simple window and displays the value of a string variable. Also, I got it to print the key you press in the console, however I want to be able to add these characters to a string, so you can see what you type. This is kind of an essential part of a text based game :)

I'd appreciate anyone's help with this. Thanks

Comment: What you _probably_ want is an `Entry` (or a fancier textbox-like control), rather than trying to handle keystrokes manually. Is there a reason that's not appropriate, or do you want an answer showing how to do that?

Comment: I've heard of entries before, but I've never researched them. I don't really want a pop up text box, rather just the text shows up in the window. If it's not too much work, it would be nice to see an example, but it's not a big deal.

Comment: It's not a popup window, just an editable box within your window. I'll write an example to show you.

Answer (score 0):

The code below shows how to use an [`Entry`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) to get text input from the user, instead of trying to handle key events manually.

It also shows two different ways you can have the user trigger you—hitting the enter/return key while the Entry has focus will call your `enter` function, while clicking the button will call your `click` function. There are all kinds of other things you can trigger off—each change to the contents, each keypress, the Entry losing focus, … But these two should be enough to show the idea.

Finally, it shows how to use the contents of the `Entry` to modify your `Text`, instead of just printing something to the console. The trick here is that a read-only Text is even read-only to `insert`/etc. methods, so you have to temporarily switch to NORMAL. (The [`Text`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) docs explain this about a third of the way down the page.)

```
from Tkinter import *

w=Tk()

textvar="Welcome, to the PIT OF INSANLEY INTENSE THINGS... AND STUFF!!!"

t=Text(w)
t.insert(INSERT,textvar)
t.configure(state=DISABLED)
t.pack()

def do_command(command):
    t.configure(state=NORMAL)
    t.insert(INSERT, '\nYou said, "{}"'.format(command))
    t.configure(state=DISABLED)

e=Entry()
e.pack(side=BOTTOM)

def enter(event):
    do_command(e.get())

e.bind('<KeyRelease-Return>', enter)

def click():
    do_command(e.get())

b=Button(text='DOIT!', command=click)
b.pack(side=BOTTOM)

w.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you think I could just change 'print' to 'return' so I could display the text in the window?

Comment: Well, just `return` won't do anything. But you _can_ change it to add the Entry contents to the end of the Text contents, or anything else you want. Let me edit it to show how.

Comment: Thanks for all your help abarnert. now I somewhat have a chance to have a playable demo for my friend on Saturday!